# Display some HTML when mouse over in a table row using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table `tr` and it looks like this:

```
<tbody>                             
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>
            <a href="" class="name">This is Pet Name</a>
            <div class="manage-link">
                <a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a> | <a href="">View</a>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>Administrator</td>
        <td><a href="">German Shepherd</a>, <a href="">Dogs</a></td>
        <td class="center">View</td>
        <td><span>2015/06/16</span>Added</td>
    </tr>   

    ....

    ....

</tbody>
```

Using this code what I need is, `manage-link` DIV should be only display when I mouse over on this `tr`.

This is how I tried it. But I couldn't get it to work.

```
td div.manage-link {
    display: none;
}

tbody tr:hover + td div.manage-link {
    display: block;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: `tbody tr:hover td div.manage-link {
    display: block;
}`, removed `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
tbody tr:hover + td div.manage-link {
    display: block;
}
```

To:

```
tbody tr:hover td div.manage-link {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: yes its working now.. can you tell me why didn't it work with `+`?

Comment: + is to target adjacent  elements.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is using JQuery with mouseenter and mouseleave events, so that you are not forced to change tr display attribute.

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('tr').mouseenter(function(){
    $('div.manage-link').css('display','block');
  });
  $('tr').mouseleave(function(){
    $('div.manage-link').css('display','none');
  });
}
```